# How to create a custom chrome exe with parameters

Tags: windows, google-chrome, parameters, customization, exe

How do I create a custom exe for chrome that already contains custom parameters?

*For example:*

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=https://www.website.com/login.php?auth=02QxCfIgjZcm5ixanXha
```

But instead of creating a shortcut then putting the parameters, it will be an exe same as chrome that already contains the custom parameters. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? what do you want to accomplish by doing this? It is possible, but I don't understand why.

Comment: i want to be able to provide a link to a website from the custom exe, as you can see there is a code on the link of the URL "auth=02QxCfIgjZcm5ixanXha" the exe will point to the link but also hiding the content of the URL and also the location of the URL itself hence making it an application that is using chrome as a medium.

Comment: Yes, but what is the point of hiding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your reasons for wanting to do this, but the simplest way I can think of to accomplish this is with a batch file to exe compiler. You put your commandline into a windows batch file, and then use for example:
[bat2exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bat2exe/) to compile it into an exe.

Or if you are not put off by a little C programming there is a short snippet with one of the `exec` functions that would work.